# Endorsements from multiple orgs within the hyperledger-fabric java sdk client

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Using Fabric and the Java SDK.

I have a requirement for a transaction to be endorsed by two organizations before it can be added to the ledger.

There's no facility to associate multiple clients (org.peers) with a `Channel` - it comes from `client.newChannel` and has a transient ref to a single `HFClient` instance in the constructor.

A single org endorsement requires me to build a `TransactionProposalRequest` and put it to the channel I already created.

The `ProposalResponse` collection that returns (one from each of the peers) is then parsed and if it is ok sent to the orderer.

I'm at a loss as to how to join more orgs to a channel.

Do I need to instantiate more `HFClient`s and have multiple copies of the `Channel`, one for each org, and then call the different channel/client combos one by one and aggregate the responses.

This (imo) implies that you need to know **all** the endorsers for your chaincode and call them one at a time. This surely can't be correct for a consortium that's being managed by multiple orgs?

Am I missing something and there is a cleaner way to do it?

The Tx flow in the docs seemed to imply that you connect to a single client and the transaction is propagated to **all** the peers for endorsement from that client.

Answer (score 0):

Just working through this myself and not totally clear.

1. Set the endorsement policy when you instantiate the chaincode (on 1 channel).
   CLI example: -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
2. (Both org's peers must be joined to the channel and have the cc installed).
3. So the cc knows what peers are required to endorse a transaction. I think that should mostly be handled by the client. (I'm using Node SDK, but they are about the same)
4. But you still need the endpoint and the ca cert from the other orgs. I found this somewhere in some IBM docs.

'If you want to target additional peers in the network, for example, you require endorsement from a peer that does not belong to your organization, then you need to obtain the correct API endpoint information of those peers. You also need to store the CA cert for the other organization to verify responses that return to your application. This information is not exposed in your service credentials, therefore you must contact the appropriate admin for the Bluemix Org and acquire this information in an out-of-band operation. The ordering service URL is common across the network; you don't need any member-specific information for ordering service.'

In Node we use a network config JSON with entries something like (not perfect)...

```
"channels": {
"peers": {
            "org1peer": {
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "ledgerQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
},

            "org2peer": {
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "ledgerQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
            }
        }
```

and

```
"peers": {
    "org1peer": {
        "url": "grpc://org1peer.org1.com:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://org1peer.org1.com:7053"
    },

    "org2peer": {
        "url": "grpc://org2peer.org2.com:7051",
        "eventUrl": "grpc://org2peer.org2.com:7053"
    }
```

and

```
"organizations": {
    "Org1MSP": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peers": [
            "org1peer"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "fabric-ca1"
        ],
        "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "./crypto/org1/bpn/admin/msp/keystore/a4941a637013e_sk"
        },
        "signedCert": {
            "path": "./crypto/org1/bpn/org1peer/msp/signcerts/cert.pem"
        }
    },

    "Org2MSP": {
        "mspid": "Org2MSP",
        "peers": [
            "org2peer"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "fabric-ca2"
        ],
        "adminPrivateKey": {
            "path": "./crypto/org2/bpn/admin/msp/keystore/04c5a4992d5_sk"
        },
        "signedCert": {
            "path": "./crypto/org2/bpn/org2peer/msp/signcerts/cert.pem"
        }
    }
},
```

Hopefully that helps you some and I look forward to better answers.

Comment: When contacting a peer from another organization you first need to enroll with that organization's CA, in order to correctly sign the proposal with credentials the peer can verify, right? You need an ID/enrollment secret for each Org.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's worse than it at first seems.

It's possible - but seems a ridiculously convoluted process - to get the endorsements from another peer (set) if you create another client for the org and instantiate another copy of the channel with the peers for that org. You need the certs, but in my case I have all of them for all the orgs, so that's not the problem.

So you have a set of responses from multiple clients (orgs). They are all ok and you'd think that submitting them to the orderer would be sufficient, no?

Well that doesn't work.

`Orderer. Cause: UNSUCCESSFUL. FORBIDDEN-403, Additional information: Failed to reach implicit threshold of 1 sub-policies, required 1 remaining: permission denied`

It looks like you can't submit a transaction to the orderer that's signed by a different org than the one that your client is designed to represent.

Which leaves me frankly stuck. The submit to orderer (or as I like to think of it - commit) isn't something that can be spread out across multiple clients. It appears to be an atomic operation.

I'm starting to wonder if anyone has actually done this...